# Which 1848 German revolutionaries became key players in the US Republican party?

Tags: united-states, political-history, germany, revolution, political-party

Gillian Brockell wrote in an [article at the WP](https://www.washingtonpost.com/history/2019/07/27/you-know-who-was-into-karl-marx-no-not-aoc-abraham-lincoln/):

> In 1860, two major factors helped to propel Lincoln — a one-term
> congressman and country lawyer most known for losing a Senate campaign
> — to the Republican nomination for the presidency. First, the support
> of former German revolutionaries who had become key players in the
> Republican Party; and second, the support of the party’s newspaper,
> the Tribune.

So, who were these former German revolutionaries? A quick search did not locate names.

Comment: The references in the [wiki article on Forty-Eighters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forty-Eighters#United_States) may be a good place to start.

Comment: ...particularly under "Political Activists". Interesting topic.

Comment: I batch of my own ancestors are Germans who arrived in the US right around this time.  I wish I had more details on them in particular.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a list-type question, and "key-player" a rather wobbly defined term.

Therefore, this answer is a community wiki. Please help to fill in the gaps.

- [Franz Sigel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Sigel)
- [Friedrich Hecker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Hecker)
- [Lorenz Brentano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenzo_Brentano)
- [Carl Schurz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Schurz)
- [Edward Salomon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Salomon)
- [Gustav Struve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_Struve)
- [Karl Bernays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Ludwig_Bernays)

Comment: Carl Schurz had become a key figure for the Democratic Party by the end of his life, supporting Bryan for president in 1900 and Parker in 1904.